# Learn button on vocabulary.com does not show on all words

Tags: vocabulary.com

Why is the **Learn** button not displayed in all word pages of vocabulary.com?

For example, on ["whistle"](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/whistle) it shows the **Learn** button on the sidebar area. But for another word, say [troll](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/troll), it doesn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only words that have exercises written for them will show the Learn button. It's part of the challenge feature with understanding more of that particular word.

> We’ve added a “Learn” button to show you which lists are ready to go. Clicking on the button will take you immediately to a Challenge that's tailored to the words you're interested in — anything from literary terms to words in the news.
>
> [Vocabularians Rejoice. List Learning is Here.](http://www.vocabulary.com/articles/announcements/vocabularians-rejoice-list-learning-is-here/)

You are not seeing it on many words, e.g., "troll", because they have yet to write up a test or lesson to go with it that will help you understand and learn how to use the word.